# Symfony 1.4 functional test and Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I'm new to funcional tests, and today I wanted to start with my first one.
I've googled for finding a good guide but there's not so much.

Now, my problem is that I want to test the click on a link, with a particular text.
And this I'm able to do.
But this link opens a Bootstrap Modal Window, and when I try to test it, I get an error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare active() (previously declared in /mypath/apps/frontend/templates/_header.php:4) in /mypath/apps/frontend/templates/_header.php on line 11`

"active" is a function written on the top of the _header.php file, which is included in the template file.
It seems that the modal recall the page creation...

For now, my code is very easy:

```
<?php

// test/functional/frontend/categoryActionsTest.php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../bootstrap/functional.php');

$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());

$browser->info('1 - The homepage')->
  get('/registrazione')->
  info('Login click')->
  with('request')->begin()->
    isParameter('module', 'registrazione')->
    isParameter('action', 'index')->
  end()->

  click('Login')->
  with('request')->begin()->
  end()
;
```

Any suggestion?!
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "this link opens a Bootstrap Modal Window"? If you open a modal window with Javascript then remember that you can't test JS with the `sfBrowser`. And another thing ""active" is a function written on the top of the _header.php". You shouldn't declare functions in your partial. If you want to have a function available in a template create a helper and include the helper.

Comment: Ok, you're right for the helper suggestion... :)
But (I repeat that I'm new to functional test) isn't there any way for test a modal window that appear when a link in clicked?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but not with the `sfBrowser` class. You would have to use something like `Sahi` or `zombie.js` to test Javascript. I'm not sure though how to integrate them with Sf 1.4. functional testing. You can also try to switch to Behat and Mink which will enable you to easily use the Sahi and Zombie drivers.